# can AWS Database Migration Service only migrate a couple of tables or columns?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, database-migration

Can **AWS Database Migration Service** only migrate a couple of tables or columns, instead of all the schemas?

I have a situation with a Database that always has changes for **dev**, adding columns and tables. One day we want to pass these changes to the **production** database but in this database there is information about current users, information of the app, etc. Would they erase or affect this information when passing the changes with the migration?

Comment: I don't think you can use AWS DMS to _change_ table formats. It can _create_ the tables and copy the data, but I don't think it is designed for changing the structure of current tables. Its purpose is to copy an existing database to a destination that is either empty or partly-migrated.

Comment: So aws not working for database version control, I was looking for that with aws solutions or without aws.